# How to create a javascript function to get the last message time similar to WhatsApp

Tags: javascript

I want to create a javascript function  to get the last message time similar to WhatsApp
if time is today return hours: minutes
if time is yesterday return "yesterday"
if time is during this week return day name ex: "Monday"
else return date ex: "day/month/year"

Can you help me?

solved I will put my solution here maybe someone will use it later

```
toDate(unix_timestamp) {
  let date = new Date(unix_timestamp * 1000);
  let currentDate = new Date();
  const timeDiff = currentDate.getTime() - date.getTime();

  if (timeDiff <= (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
    //Today
    return moment(date).format('h:mm a');
  } else if (timeDiff <= (48 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
    // Yesterday
    return "Yesterday"
  }else if(timeDiff <=  (168 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
    // Less than week
    return moment(date).format('dddd')
  } else {
    return moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code you need help with? We don't write code for people on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show your effort in solving this question and share your code so that people can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically [Intl.RelativeTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat/RelativeTimeFormat) should help here, but the most popular library to date is [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) which documentation includes various discussions around this topic, and it mentions the Temporal API, which has even less browsers support.